# Нет возможности отправить email SmtpClient C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

Здравствуйте!

Появилась необходимость написать отправку по почте, вроде ничего нового и примеров полно, но при попытки отправить сообщение получаю исключение. Вот код:

```
using (SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("host", 110))
        {
            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            sc.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@host.ru", "pass");

            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@host.ru");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("to@host.ru");

            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to))
            {
                message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                message.Body = result;
                message.Subject = "test message";
                message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                sc.Send(message);
            }
        }
```

собственно исключение:

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [19300] SmtpClient::.ctor(host=host, port=110)
System.Net Information: 0 : [19300] Associating SmtpClient#28657176 with         SmtpTransport#53682564
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [19300] Exiting SmtpClient::.ctor()     -> SmtpClient#28657176
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [19300]     SmtpClient#28657176::Send(MailMessage#40097817)
System.Net Information: 0 : [19300] SmtpClient#28657176::Send(DeliveryMethod=Network)
System.Net Information: 0 : [19300] Associating SmtpClient#28657176 with MailMessage#40097817
System.Net Information: 0 : [19300] Текущий тип установки операционной системы: Client.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [19300] ServicePoint#65970676::ServicePoint(host:110)
System.Net Information: 0 : [19300] Associating SmtpTransport#53682564 with SmtpConnection#24995927
System.Net Information: 0 : [19300] Associating SmtpConnection#24995927 with ServicePoint#65970676
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Socket#52434070::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Exiting Socket#52434070::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Socket#61012415::Socket(AddressFamily#23)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Exiting Socket#61012415::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] DNS::TryInternalResolve(host)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Socket#52434070::Connect(host:110#352387940)
System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [19300] Socket#52434070 - Создано подключение с client:53099 к host:110.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Exiting Socket#52434070::Connect() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Socket#61012415::Close()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Socket#61012415::Dispose()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Exiting Socket#61012415::Close() 
System.Net Information: 0 : [19300] SmtpPooledStream#42866877 - Создано подключение с client:53099 к host:110.
System.Net Information: 0 : [19300] Associating SmtpConnection#24995927 with SmtpPooledStream#42866877
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Socket#52434070::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Data from Socket#52434070::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] 00000000 : 2B 4F 4B 20 44 6F 76 65-63 6F 74 20 72 65 61 64 : +OK Dovecot read
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] 00000010 : 79 2E 0D 0A                                     : y...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Exiting Socket#52434070::Receive()  -> Int32#20
System.Net Error: 0 : [19300] Исключение в SmtpClient#28657176::Send - Синтаксическая ошибка. Команда не опознана. Отклик сервера: Dovecot ready..
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [19300] Socket#52434070::Dispose()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [19300] SmtpPooledStream::Dispose #42866877
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [19300] Exiting SmtpPooledStream::Dispose #42866877
System.Net Error: 0 : [19300] Исключение в AppDomain#33044831::UnhandledExceptionHandler - Синтаксическая ошибка. Команда не опознана. Отклик сервера: Dovecot ready..
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   в SendMail.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SendMail\SendMail\Program.cs:строка 104
   в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [19300] Exiting SmtpClient#28657176::Send()
```

Если кто сталкивался, прошу помочь или направить куда можно копнуть. Спасибо!

Comment: Была похожая проблема, долго не мог понять в чем дело, пока не поменял имя ПК с кирилицы на латиницу. Возможно у вас та же ситуация

Comment: а почему вы отправляете через 110-й порт? Как минимум 25-й нужен

Comment: читал про такую возможность, но машина доменная и имя на английском.

Comment: может фаервол и антивирусник блокируют ?

Comment: Порт 110 - это получение почты по протоколу POP3, 25тый отправка по протоколу SMTP. Вы пытаетесь отправить и должны для этого идти на 25тый порт, а не на 110, @defrag вам правильно говорит. Точное значение порта нужно спрашивать у админов сервера, это может быть и порт 2525 и ещё более другие варианты.

Comment: всё верно, с кокого-то перепуга использовал 110й порт. Всем спасибо большое!

Comment: Ну и прекрасно: закрыть как "вызван опечаткой или не воспроизводится"

Comment: блин, я думал это в вопросе опечатка - не 25 а 100 )